# Transcription of list items - how to punctuate two-word sentences

Tags: punctuation

How would you punctuate two-word sentences that begin with a sequence word?

[Sequence word] [noun].

I see this often when transcribing PowerPoint presentations, where I do not change the word content and the speaker is reading off of a list. I am trying to decide whether it flows better to use commas, colons, or even em-dashes or semi-colons. I essentially would like to indicate the implication of "is" between these two words, without using punctuation that is overly distracting.

1. [Sequence word], [noun].
2. [Sequence word]: [noun].
3. [Sequence word]—[noun].
4. [Sequence word]; [noun].

Here are some examples of what I see:

> Firstly, appearance. The appearance of your app will be one of
> your most important areas of focus. [...]
>
> Secondly, setup. The metaphor I normally use with this is designing a
> table. [...]
>
> Finally, data storage. Using SQL or the another database. As with
> all software development, databases are needed for storage and
> recall of user information. [...]

Thanks in advance for any input. I searched for a while using terms like "two-word sentence" and "sequence words", etc, but didn't find anything relevant, so was probably looking with the wrong keywords or am perhaps approaching this from the wrong angle.

Edit: researching this more, it seems the best search terms for this may be "punctuation in nominal sentences", so I'll update this post if I find anything useful.

Comment: They're fragments, not sentences, so any reasonably sensible punctuation is fair game. Ruling out silly possibilities like question marks, and exclamation marks, we're left with commas, semicolons, dashes,  ellipses and full stops. The full stop seems best to close off what is essentially a complete notion / class. Commas are used in sentences after pragmatic markers (here, formatting/collating/sequencing), so why not here too?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks for the reply. I agree that commas make sense here. I am wondering if there is a misunderstanding, though, since you're bringing up full stops. In my question, I'm just talking about the punctuation between [Sequence word] and [noun], like the comma in "Firstly, appearance." I can't imagine this being written as "Firstly. Appearance."

Comment: Yes. [Structuring discourse marker],[Heading/Title]. A,B. Fifthly, Possible Drawbacks.